# VS 2022 Javascript Debugging in ASP.net not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I have a debug point set in one of my .cshtml files that is not being loaded when I debug.

The warning message shown when I hover over it is: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Unbound breakpoint".

I have "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome, Edge, and IE)" checked in Options > Debugging > General

I've found quite a few related questions, but none of the answers I've seen have worked for me yet.

Things I've already tried:

1. Restart VS > Clean and Rebuild
2. Delete the .vs file, Restart VS then rebuild
3. Disable and Re-enable the JS Debugging setting
4. Try different browsers(Chrome, Edge and IE)

It's been awhile(5 or 6 years) since I've needed javascript debugging, but I know for sure it used to work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Prof 64 bit version 17.7.4, and Chrome Version 121.0.6167.160

Projects in the solution are all running on .net version 4.8

Any ideas?

Comment: JS/client-side debugging in VS has always, and continues to be, useless. I'd suggest an alternative, such as setting breakpoints in devtools within your browser.

Comment: That's what I'm resorting to atm, but it's just really slow and cumbersome because there are so many different things I need to log. Generally console.log is all I've needed, which is why it's been so long since I've used the feature

Comment: You should look into the `debugger` keyword in javascript. This will trigger a debugging breakpoint in the browser at runtime where you can inspect the script via the different dev tools that are provided by the browser itself.